A function that measures compositeness
When working on a problem in probabilistic number theory, I was trying to prove the existence of a coupling of some number-theoretical variables subject to some constraints. In the process (and before I learned to apply Hall's/Strassen's Theorem), I created some function $P$ which measures compositeness. In particular, $P:\mathbb{N}\to [0,1)$, $$P\left(j\right) = 1 - \frac{1+\sum_{p \vert j}\left(p-1\right)}{j},$$
where the sum is over the distinct prime factors of $j$.
Some properties of $P$ are

$P\left(j\right)=0$ if and only if $j$ is 1 or $j$ is prime;
Of all composite numbers, $P$ says that $6$ is the least composite in the sense that $P\left(6\right)=1/3$ is the smallest nonzero value for $P$. In particular, $P$ claims that $2\cdot 3$ is less composite than $2\cdot2$ since $P\left(4\right)=1/2$.
As expected, there is no largest $P$ value (i.e., no "most composite number"); e.g., $P\left(2^n\right) = 1-1/2^{n-1} \to 1$.
In addition, I have a method that naturally extends $P$ to a multivariate function that can be used to measure relative compositeness among lists (e.g., $P\left(4, 8\right) = 1/2 > 1/3 = P\left(4, 9\right)$. However, the formula becomes tedious even in the 2-dimensional case: if $a=\prod p_{k}^{a_k}$ and $b=\prod p_{k}^{b_k}$, then

$$P(a,b) = 1 - \left(\frac{1}{a}\left(\sum_{a_{k} \ge 1}\left(p_{k}- 1\right)\right)+1\right) - \left(\frac{1}{b}\left(\sum_{b_{k} \ge 1}\left(p_{k}- 1\right)\right)+1\right)\\
\phantom{P(a,b) = } + \frac{1}{\text{lcm}(a,b)}\left(\sum_{a_k - b_k \ge 1}\left(p_k - 1\right)+1\right)\left(\sum_{b_k - a_k \ge 1}\left(p_k - 1\right)+1\right)$$

Poset Structure: Say $a \preceq b$ if $\frac{a}{\gcd(a,i)}$ is composite implies  $\frac{b}{\gcd(b,i)}$ is composite. If $a \preceq b$, then $P(a) \le P(b)$ and $P(a,b) = P(a)$.
$P$ is not a measure since it is not additive: $P(4,9) = 1/3 < 1/2 + 2/3 = P(4) + P(9)$


Is there an avenue in number theory where such a function or its properties would be of interest? Admittedly, I came about this function in a round-about way.


There are many functions that measure the compositeness of a number. For example, I defined in one of my works a notion of the entropy of a natural number which vanishes if and only if the number is prime (and is not defined if the number is $1$). After doing this I learned that Minculete and Pozna had previously defined the entropy of a natural number in a different way which vanishes if and only if the number is a prime power, and then that an anonymous stackexchange user gave another definition of the entropy of a natural number which is very small if the number is prime

and can be modified to vanish if and only if the number is prime, by removing $1$ from the sum over divisors. So all of these could be seen as measures of the compositeness of a number, and these are just examples based on the probabilistic definition of entropy. There are surely many more ways than that of measuring the compositeness of a number. What makes any one interesting is probably not any particular feature it has but rather its relevance in solving a particular problem.

If your function $P$ helps in solving your problem, then it may be quite interesting.  But if as it seems to be the case you found it's not actually necessary for the problem you developed it for, the chance that it will be useful for something else is less (though certainly not zero).
